# Should we include constant in linear regression in pairs trading?

Tags: time-series, quant-trading-strategies, algorithmic-trading, pairs-trading

Should we include constant in linear regression while calculating hedge ratio for pairs trading strategy?

Answer (score 2):

### **Yes**

For two asset-price processes $Y_t$ and $X_t$ that are both $I(1)$ and **cointegrated**, the error-term, $z_t$, of the linear regression model,

$$
Y_t = \mu + \beta \cdot X_t + z_t
$$

is $I(0)$ (*see [Verbeek, M. (2008). A guide to modern econometrics](https://thenigerianprofessionalaccountant.files.wordpress.com/2013/04/modern-econometrics.pdf), p. 315*). In the above regression, $\beta$ denotes the hedge ratio and $\mu$ denotes the long-run equilibrium value which can be seen by rearranging the regression and **obtaining the spread** to be used in your pairs trading strategy:

$$
\underset{Spread}{\underbrace{Y_t - \beta X_t}}  = \mu +  z_t   
$$

The reason $\mu$ is occasionally omitted from the regression is due to the fact that, it's estimated when calculating the Z-score of the spread (*ie. normalizing the spread*). Here, $z_t$ has zero mean and variance $\sigma^2$ and as such, the **normalization of the spread** is $\frac{z_t-\mu}{\sigma}$, which we use to derive the signals for the trading strategy.