# Pairs trading gradient

Tags: regression, pairs-trading, allocation

For a pairs trade, when calculating the zscore should I include the gradient (slope) from OLS in the calculation:

```
spread = price2 - (gradient * price1)
zscore = (spread - average)/standard_deviation
```

Should the spread calculation include the gradient:

```
spread = price2 - (gradient * price1)
```

or just

```
spread = price2 - price1
```

?

How would I use the gradient for the quantities of asset 1 and asset 2 ?

I would like to buy a maximum of $100 or either asset 1 or asset 2 ?

Comment: Maybe this [post](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/71550/51407) would be of help.

Comment: Yes, of course, it matters for the quantities. If one stock price is about 10 times the other price you need one tenth as many shares of the first as you do of the second, to get comparably valued long and short positions.

Comment: Thanks nbbo2

How would I use the gradient for the quantities of asset 1 and asset 2 ?
I would like to buy a maximum of $100 for either asset 1 or asset 2 ?